# How to draw scrolling background?

Tags: android, opengl-es, parallax

How can i draw background tile in my 2D side-scrolling game?Is that loop logical for OpenGL es?My tile 2400x480.Also i want to use parallax scrolling for my game.

```
batcher.beginBatch(Assets.background);

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    batcher.drawSprite(0+2400*i, 240, 2400, 480, Assets.backgroundRegion);

    batcher.endBatch();
```